# Yahoo BOSS API issue

Tags: apache, yahoo-boss-api

I have a Yahoo BOSS API project that makes use of OAuth and isn't working on my new Apache2 server. I know its nothing to do with the files cause I copy and pasted them from my old server which still works. phpinfo() confirms that OAuth is installed but whenever I make a query a blank page is returned instead of the search results. What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Is your BOSS PHP page doing an include to your oauth.php page?  Are your results set to JSON or XML coming back from BOSS?